# Understanding better this physical phrase

Tags: gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

> *In field theory, symmetry governs the dynamics by restricting the form of the Lagrangian from which all relevant equations and interactions are derived. An example of symmetry transformations is multiplication of the fields by a complex number. When we make different transformations at different space-time points, we must introduce a new field in order to maintain the symmetry. This new field is called the gauge field and is responsible for the interactions among various particles.*

Why is it that: "When we make different transformations at different space-time points, we must introduce a new field in order to maintain the symmetry."?

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Quote taken from where?

Comment: @Qmechanic http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jus/0302/song.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we know what type of gauge field to add to a theory?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129245/)