# Do fermions have groups like how gauge bosons have gauge groups?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, gauge-theory, fermions, bosons

As I understand it, the Lie groups $U(1)$, $SU(2)$, and $SU(3)$ correspond to the electromagnetic, weak, and strong forces respectively (ignoring electroweak mixing) and the generators of their associated Lie algebras correspond to their respective gauge bosons. Are there groups that describe fermions or do these also arise from $U(1)$, $SU(2)$, and $SU(3)$?

Comment: The closest thing you can get is to have a gauge theory with supersymmetry.  The result is not a group, but the fermion fields can play a role similar to the spin-1 boson fields in an ordingary gauge theory.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100578/20427

Comment: Well, the fermions also reside in representations of the symmetry groups, just like the gauge bosons.

Comment: The gauge transformations are named after their effects on the fermions.